# How to extend default options with Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to extend default values with options in angular way:

```
var defaultOptions = {
      a: 'a'
    },
    options = {
      b: 'b'
    };
var result = $.extend({}, defaultOptions, options);
```

Please notice, that `result` is a new object, because I want to preserve both of the original objects `defaultOptions` and `options`.

**I'm new in Angular, could you please help me to do the same `result` with angular in the most elegant way?**

EDIT:

I have already found `angular.extend()` but I can't figure out a way how to preserve `defaultOptions` and `options`.

I know that I can do it this way:

```
var result = angular.extend({}, defaultOptions);
angular.extend(result, options);
```

But it doesn't look very elegant.

Comment: @Satpal I want to preserve both of the original objects, `defaultOptions` and `options`.

Comment: @Satpal I need to do the same with Angular, not jQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [**angular.extend**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend)

> Extends the destination object dst by copying all of the properties from the src object(s) to dst. You can specify multiple src objects.

*Usage*

```
var result = angular.extend({}, defaultOptions, options)
```

Answer (score 3):

Angular provides an [extend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend) function.

```
var result = angular.extend({},defaultOptions, options)
```

Comment: Does it support multiple arguments?

Answer (score 0):

you can use angular [copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

```
var result = angular.copy(defaultOptions );
```